# Proof of character of representation corresponding to a nonsquare matrix

Tags: representation-theory, characters

So I am working on a problem from *Steinberg's representation theory of finite groups*. I am stuck on exercise $4.11$ (the second part) and can't find the solution anywhere. It goes like this:

> Let $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ be finite groups and let $G=G_{1}\times G_{2}$. Suppose $\rho:G_{1}\rightarrow GL_{m}(\mathbb{C})$ and $ \varphi:G_{2}\rightarrow GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ are representations. Let $V=M_{mn}(\mathbb{C})$ . Define $\tau:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ by $\tau_{(g_{1},g_{2})}(A)=\rho_{g_{1}}A\varphi _{g_{2}}.$

The first part asked to prove it was a representation and that was doable, but the second part i find confusing:
prove that $$\chi_{\tau}(g_{1},g_{2})=\chi_{\rho}(g_{1})\chi_{\varphi}(g_{2}). $$
I for one am confused about how I must read $\tau_{(g_{1},g_{2})}$ as a matrix as it's sandwiched in between the two functions so to speak. Do I need to find a matrix such that when multiplied by a matrix $A$, it yields $\tau_{(g_{1},g_{2})}(A)$? Secondly, I am confused on how to find the trace of $\tau_{(g_{1},g_{2})}$ in the first place. Isn't it an $m\times n$ matrix? If not, (again) what form does it have? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need to take the trace of $\tau_{(g_1, g_2)}$, which is in $GL(V)$. For this you can take the trace.

Comment: So does that mean it is an $m\times m$-matrix?

Comment: The confusion probably comes from a fact, that here elements of $G$ act not only as matrices, but on matrices too. So I guess it'll be useful to choose a base on $V$ consisting of matrices $E_{ij}$ (one in $i$-th row and $j$-th column, zero elsewhere) and look at how the group element is working on them.

Comment: The vector space $V=M_{mn}(\mathbb{C})$ has dimension $mn$. Thus, if you wish to represent $\tau_{(g_1,g_2)}$ as a matrix, then it would be a $(mn)\times (mn)$ matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry I am still confused. It does make sense, but then how can one take the product of matrices that don't match the amount of columns and rows (in the definition of $\tau$)?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a step back. Consider the linear map $T$ given by $T(A) = MAC$ where $M$ and $C$ are $m\times m$ and $n\times n$ diagonalizable matrices respectively.  First verify that $T$ is a linear map for a $m\cdot n$ dimensional vector space. Then compute T's trace. With respect to the trace, the typical approaches are (i) use Kronecker Products or (ii) take advantage of $M$ and $C$ being diagonalizable-- you can figure out the eigenvectors (and hence eigenvalues) of $T$-- then sum over all eigenvalues to get the trace (hint: focus on rank one matrices to find the eigenvectors of $T$)